# How to import specific Python Libraries using External Evaluate

Tags: python, external-calls

I want to use specific python libraries via the Mathematica frontend. This is possible as follows

```
In[30]:= ExternalEvaluate["Python", "from sympy import isprime; isprime(7)"]

Out[30]= True
```

However, if I directly try to evaluate the same using > at the beginning of a line to use an external code cell, this does not work. For instance,

```
> from sympy import isprime; isprime(7)
```

gives as output,

Failure[[WarningSign]  Message:    No module named 'sympy'
Tag:    PythonError
]

Any ideas on how to make this work from external code cells.

Comment: It works for me on 13.2 with some modules e.g os, sys, math and so on. Maybe it's something to do with the PYTHONPATH. Try `import sys; sys.path` in both ExternalEvaluate and the code cell and see if there's a difference.

Comment: If I _pip install sympy_ globally (as admin) then importing sympy works and both evaluate to True, so either you're on an older Mathematica where there's a discrepancy between the two choices of path, or something is wrong with your python setup.

Comment: @flinty: Thanks a lot. Yes there was a difference in the sys.path between the two as the external code cell was accessing a different python distribution. After unregistering the problematic one, things are fine.